# How firebase persistence stores local data for my Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android app similar to WhatsApp.
In the app users can send text as well as images.
To save the messages so that they can be viewed offline I used :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

I was wondering how does firebase store messages offline.

**Does it create a local database similar to the commonly used sqlite?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The disk based local storage of the Firebase Database is a sqlite database that is structured opaquely in a way that your app shouldn't care about. The only way you should access the data is through the Firebase API.

Comment: There are a lot of libraries that handle the caching of images for you. One example: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Does a folder of my app's database gets created in the device storage just like for many android apps